# SPF for domain and subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain, spf

I have a question about SPF records (i not a huge expert of DNS)
In main domain (mydomain.com) we have mail server and our DNS have such a records (mx, a and txt):

```
           IN      MX      10 mail.mydomain.com.
mail            IN      A       1.1.1.1
mail            IN      A       2.2.2.2
mydomain.com.       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 a:mail.mydomain.com ~all"
```

Now we have to install additional mail serwer in dedicate subdomain (mysubdomain.mydomain.com).
I have plan to send emails from this subdomain using zimbra.
I have a question so records in DNS are correct::

```
                IN      MX      10 mail.mydomain.com.
mysubdomain             IN      MX      10 mail1.mydomain.com.
mail                 IN      A       1.1.1.1
mail                 IN      A       2.2.2.2
mail1                IN      A       3.3.3.3
mail1                IN      A       4.4.4.4
mysubdomain          IN      A       3.3.3.3
mysubdomain          IN      A       4.4.4.4
mydomain.com.               IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 a:mail.mydomain.com ~all"
mysubdomain.mydomain.com.       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:3.3.3.3 ip4:4.4.4.4 a:mail1.mydomain.com ~all"
```

Please tell me, so is are correct or i should done some changes?

Best regards,
bcteam

Comment: DNS configuration is not a programming question, and as such unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Perhaps you want to ask over on our sister site [sf] or perhaps [unix.se]

Answer (score -1):

Your records look OK apart from the mail servers. Instead of explicitly using `a` clauses and the mail server host names, just use an `mx` clause. Instead of:

```
mydomain.com.               IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 a:mail.mydomain.com ~all"
mysubdomain.mydomain.com.       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:3.3.3.3 ip4:4.4.4.4 a:mail1.mydomain.com ~all"
```

say:

```
mydomain.com.               IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 mx ~all"
mysubdomain.mydomain.com.       IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:3.3.3.3 ip4:4.4.4.4 mx ~all"
```

When you're done, test your setup on [Scott Kitterman's site](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).